# Definition of function composition versus composition of relations?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, relations

The definition of the composition of two relations $R_G$ and $R_F$ where $R_G \subseteqq F \times G$ and $R_F \subseteqq E \times F$ is
$$
(a, b) \in R_F \circ R_G \iff \exists x, (a, x) \in R_F \land (x, b) \in R_G
$$

However, if I have a function $f: E \to F$ and $g: F \to G$, then

$$
(g \circ f)(x) \equiv g(f(x))
$$

However, this is confusing to me, because $f$, $g$ (and thus $g \circ f$) are all relations so shouldn't $g \circ f$ be defined the other way round? As in by this definition $g \circ f$ maps elements in $E$ to elements in $G$ whereas, $R_F \circ R_G$ maps from elements in $a \in E$ to elements in $F$ but it is the other way around to $g \circ f$?

Sorry for a very elementary question (I think I've dug myself into a hole here, and maybe need to review some of the basic defintions), but these definitions were both given in a textbook I'm reading, and they seem contradictory to me.

Comment: Only a question of "tradition" in symbolization... See [Composition of relations: Notational variations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_of_relations#Notational_variations)

Comment: In the "algebraic" approach is quite natural to write $g(f(x))$ because functions are "directed" (see arrow notation): we apply $f$ to an argument $a$ to get a value $f(a)$ and then we apply function $g$ to that value as argument to get a new value $g(f(a))$.

Comment: Relations are not "arrows"; see Wiki's example: "the relation of Uncle $(x \text U z)$ is the composition of relations "is a brother of" $(x \text B y)$ and "is a parent of" $(y \text P z)$. $\text U= \text B \text P \equiv x \text B y \text Pz \iff x \text U z$".

Comment: Notations clash : "$R_G$ where $\color{red}G\subset F\times \color{red}G$". Isn't it ?